# how to move my azure table storage data to premium storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to increase the performance tier of storage account from standard to premium and migrate Azure Table Storage Data to premium storage account. Premium storage accounts do not support Table storage account.

So what I can do now and which premium account type I should select?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Table Storage, you have two options:

1. Azure Table Storage
2. Azure Cosmos DB Table API

In short: using Table Storage is the entry-level table storage. Cosmos DB is the premium version of Azure Table Storage. Although only calling it the premium version doesn't do Cosmos DB justice.

The nice thing is also that the Azure Tables client library can seamlessly target either Azure Table storage or Azure Cosmos DB table service endpoints with no code changes.
This is at least the case for the .NET client, but since the API's are compatible I would assume this to be the case for other libraries, too.

For an overview of the differences between the services, see [Introduction to Azure Cosmos DB: Table API - Table offerings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/introduction#table-offerings)

More relevant sources:

> The concepts of Azure Table storage also apply to the newer Azure Cosmos DB Table API. The Cosmos DB Table API offers higher performance and availability, global distribution, and automatic secondary indexes.

Source: [What is Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-overview)

and

> Azure Cosmos DB Table API and Azure Table storage share the same table data model and expose the same create, delete, update, and query operations through their SDKs.

Source: [Developing with Azure Cosmos DB Table API and Azure Table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/table-support)